# Blazor App - Missing Method Exception at Startup

Tags: c#, blazor

After doing file -> new -> blazor app I get the following error during in the Configure method at startup.
I have tried using the preview version of visual studio. I have .Net Core 3 preview 7 installed. I have also tried adding the nuget packages mentioned in the exception: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server, but am still getting the exception.  Any advice?

[image]

Below is the output of the dotnet --info command

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100-preview7-012821
 Commit:    6348f1068a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview8-28376-13
  Commit:  b56f4d3e9c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.701 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100-preview7-012821 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview8.19376.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview8-28376-13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0-preview8-28376-13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Please expand and clarify on what type of blazor project you created here - file->new-> blazor (server) app ...leads to three options - which one did you pick? Blazor Server App, Blazor (ASP.NET Core Hosted) or Blazor (client-side)?

Comment: The issue above comes from Blazor Server App template.  I am getting other errors as well with the other templates which I think are related to this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10964

Comment: Did you install the latest templates using the command line? `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview7.19365.7`

Comment: Did you remove any Blazor extensions from Visual Studio left over from previouse releases?

Comment: okay, using Visual studio preview 16.3 along with the Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) template (which I think comes from installing the templates based on the command you provided) is now working.  The Blazor Server App still does not work though.  For now, I will just stick with using the Hosted template as I am just doing some PoC work.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like you've got preview8 installed...

Comment: Yea, that was installed based on some work I was doing with gRPC based on Microsofts implementation/examples from GitHub.  After removing the templates and then reinstalling them using the command provided by Mister Magoo, then creating a new 'Blazor (ASP.NET Core Hosted)' project using visual studio preview 16.3 I was able to run the server project.